# Can't change global variable inside function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, variables, scopes

I have a global variable called *result* and a function, with the purpose of changing the value of result. here's the code I've tried:

```
checkdate();

function checkdate() {
    //defining startdate,enddate,hotel_id

    $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/checkdate',
    data: {startdate : startdate, enddate : enddate, checkroom : 1, hotel_id : hotel_id},
    success: function(response){
        storeResponse(response);
    }
    });
}

var result = [];
function storeResponse(response) {
    window.result = response;
}
alert(result);
```

The alert returns nothing, however if I put the alert INSIDE the function, it returns *response* alright. This seems to be easy but I can't figure it out.

The function is invoked before all this code.

Comment: Be aware depending on where `var result = []` lives it won't be available on the window object. More info on the context of where that code is executing would be helpful.

Comment: Please add more code as where in code you are calling the function and where are you trying to alert

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to know here:

1. `var result` is not same as `window.result` so use `window.result = "Test";` and not the `var` declaration.
2. You need to invoke `storeResponse()` before `alert` code so that it set the new value and then get that value in `alert`.

```js
window.result = "Test"; //in global scope
function storeResponse(response) {
    window.result = response;
    console.log(window);
}
storeResponse("Hello");
alert(result);
```

Comment: it is invoked before all this code, as I said, everything works fine if I put the alert INSIDE the function

Comment: @HessamShekhasnay that will always work if you put that alert inside. But you need to alert outside for which the function call will be before alert. If this did not work then post your actual code

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal please see the edited question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function first so that the result variable is populated.

```
var result = []; //in global scope
function storeResponse(response) {
    window.result = response;
}
storeResponse('callSomething');
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you are invoking the function first, so you must have something like this:

```
storeResponse('someResponse');
var result = []; //in global scope
function storeResponse(response) {
    window.result = response;
}

alert(result);
```

The issue is the following:

1. In first line you are calling your function. The function sets a new `result` var in the window, global scope
2. In the second line, you are overwriting the `result` var: `var result = [];` It lets you with an empty array, that's why the alert looks empty

Try commenting the second line and it will work:

```
storeResponse('someResponse');
//var result = []; //in global scope
function storeResponse(response) {
    window.result = response;
}

alert(result);
```

Or even better, declare the var first:

```js
var result = []; 
storeResponse('someResponse');

function storeResponse(response) {
result = response; // You don't need to use window (if the var is not declared inside the function, is global by default)
}

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because AJAX is asynchronous. Meaning the code is non-blocking.
Imagine the AJAX call being passed to another thread for processing while the rest of the code is executed. The alert is triggered before the AJAX request has received it's response. Thats why if you do the alert inside the callback it works.

Comment: What's the solution? the goal is to store ajax response in a global variable. and other answers on stack-overflow didn't help.

Comment: It does store it. It's just not available at the point you are requesting it. You need to query the value after the response has successfully been fetched. Using events is a good use case for this. Providing a full solution is not possible with this amount of code.